# A person full of complexes

Tags: word-request, idioms, phrases

I wonder what would you normally call someone who has a chip on their shoulder informally? (What I am looking for can be considered as an offensive idiom/expression/adjective by most people.) Such people have many complexes and most of the time treat others in an offensive, aggressive or unfair manner, because there is something eating them from inside. Psychologically they have been treated in the past very bad once or for a long time, and they want to revenge in this way; because deep down inside they consider all the surrounding people guilty.

For instance:

> **Mother:** Did you go to that department today and talk to the director? 
>   **Daughter:** No, mom! And I won't go. They're a bunch of ____________

I wonder what would you use in the blank?

Comment: I think it would depend on the origin of the complex they have, I don't know if there is a collective term for it. E.g. [misogynists](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/misogynist), [chauvinists](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/chauvinist), [homophobes](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/homophobe) etc. Maybe calling them [arrogant](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/arrogant) [x]s, or [snobs](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/snob) but I'm not sure they fit the discription?

Comment: The origins are mostly social deprivations or some unsatisfied feelings in childhood within the society and many times some comparisons between oneself and the more prosperous class of the society and sometimes just personal jealousy etc. But @Bee I am looking for an **informal** term or at least something that all people use it without sounding formal or being stilted.

Comment: As I said, I'm not sure the word you're looking for exists, although I am quite happy to be proven wrong! You might want to consider posting this on ELU instead. Personally, I'd probably just use tw*ts ;)

Comment: I see @Bee :))) But the problem is that first of all it is BE and I suspect Americans use it. Also,  it has only a vulgar usage and you cannot say it to a person you want to be a little more polite with. ;)

Comment: Ah see I call people that in front of my mum all the time!

Comment: Haha I don't think I'd recommend it in all situations, I have a pretty young and relaxed mum, plus I do think it could be more offensive in other regions/countries. I was only being cheeky.

Comment: Thought of a few synonyms for "[having a] complex". Wounded, Fixated, Damaged?

Comment: Anyway my mum won't understand me @Bee :))) So no worries. Regarding your last offers, "wounded" seems to be okay, but still it is not what I need. I guess I have to look for a scientific term for that. Just what psychologists call such a person in English spoken scientific atmosphere Bee? I mean a common word which can be understood with not only super educated peiple, but well educated ones.

Comment: I thought you were looking for an informal term? To me, that wouldn't be the same as a scientific term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I could summarise our discussion in the comments in hopes the question can be answered (or at least it will push it back to the front page where you might get someone else attempting)!

> They have a [chip on their shoulder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip_on_shoulder).

To have a chip on one's shoulder refers to the act of holding a grudge or grievance that readily provokes disputation.

> They have a bit of a [complex](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/complex_2).

To have a complex is to have an emotional problem caused by unreasonable fears or worries

> They are (emotionally) [wounded.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wounded)

To be offended or upset by what someone has said or done

> They just want {[payback](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/payback)/[retribution](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/retribution)/[vengeance](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vengeance)/[to penalise](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/penalize) me} for something I haven't done.

Payback -​
something bad that is done to you because of something bad that you have done previously
Retribution - deserved and severe punishment 
vengeance - action against someone to punish that person for having hurt you
To penalise someone - to treat someone in an unfair way and make them have a disadvantage

> They're a bunch of [narcissists](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/narcissistic).

To be narcissistic is to be extremely self-centered with an exaggerated sense of self-importance : marked by or characteristic of excessive admiration of or infatuation with oneself

Comment: I think it will just be clear from context weather you mean it as an insult or not. It's certainly negative but not always meant as an insult